# Type class definition with functions depending on an additional type

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Still new to Haskell, I have hit a wall with the following:

I am trying to define some type classes to generalize a bunch of functions that use gaussian elimination to solve linear systems of equations.

Given a linear system

```
M x = k
```

the type `a` of the elements `m(i,j) \elem M` can be different from the type `b` of `x` and `k`. To be able to solve the system, `a` should be an instance of `Num` and `b` should have multiplication/addition operators with `b`, like in the following:

```
class MixedRing b where
    (.+.) :: b -> b -> b
    (.*.) :: (Num a) => b -> a -> b
    (./.) :: (Num a) => b -> a -> b
```

Now, even in the most trivial implementation of these operators, I'll get `Could not deduce a ~ Int. a is a rigid type variable` errors (Let's forget about `./.` which requires `Fractional`)

```
data Wrap = W { get :: Int }
instance MixedRing Wrap where
    (.+.) w1 w2 = W $ (get w1) + (get w2)
    (.*.) w s   = W $ ((get w) * s)
```

I have read several tutorials on type classes but I can find no pointer to what actually goes wrong.

Comment: There's already a package that defines this class: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector-space/0.8.0/doc/html/Data-VectorSpace.html You can take a peek there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let us have a look at the type of the implementation that you would have to provide for `(.*.)` to make `Wrap` an instance of `MixedRing`. Substituting `Wrap` for `b` in the type of the method yields

```
(.*.) :: Num a => Wrap -> a -> Wrap
```

As `Wrap` is isomorphic to `Int` and to not have to think about wrapping and unwrapping with `Wrap` and `get`, let us reduce our goal to finding an implementation of

```
(.*.) :: Num a => Int -> a -> Int
```

(You see that this doesn't make the challenge any easier or harder, don't you?)

Now, observe that such an implementation will need to be able to operate on all types `a` that happen to be in the type class `Num`. (This is what a type variable in such a type denotes: universal quantification.) Note: this is not the same (actually, it's the opposite) of saying that your implementation can itself choose what `a` to operate on); yet that is what you seem to suggest in your question: that your implementation should be allowed to pick `Int` as a choice for `a`.

Now, as you want to implement this particular `(.*.)` in terms of the `(*)` for values of type `Int`, we need something of the form

```
n .*. s = n * f s
```

with

```
f :: Num a => a -> Int
```

I cannot think of a function that converts from an arbitary `Num`-type `a` to `Int` in a meaningful way. I'd therefore say that there is no meaningful way to make `Int` (and, hence, `Wrap`) an instance of `MixedRing`; that is, not such that the instance behaves as you would probably expect it to do.

Comment: Very good explanation. Actually there are 2 errors: First, one cannot instantiate a (from the class definition) in the instance definition and b) the way .*. is implemented causes b=a anyway and contradicts therefore the type of .*. given in the class.

Comment: Thank you for this excellent explanation. Together with the other answers as well as the link to the `VectorSpace` package this clarifies the issue.

Answer (score 6):

How about something like:

```
class (Num a) => MixedRing a b where
    (.+.) :: b -> b -> b
    (.*.) :: b -> a -> b
    (./.) :: b -> a -> b
```

You'll need the `MultiParamTypeClasses` extension.

By the way, it seems to me that the mathematical structure you're trying to model is really *module*, not a ring. With the type variables given above, one says that *`b` is an `a`-module*.

Comment: Didn't know there are multi parameter type classes, this works. And you are right of course, module is the correct term. Physicist, not mathematician here, an approximation is good enough ;)

Answer (score 2):

Your implementation is not polymorphic enough.

The rule is, if you write `a` in the class definition, you can't use a concrete type in the instance. Because the instance must conform to the class and the class promised to accept any `a` that is `Num`.

To put it differently: Exactly the class variable is it that must be instantiated with a concrete type in an instance definition.

Have you tried:

```
data Wrap a = W { get :: a }
```

Note that once `Wrap a` is an instance, you can still use it with functions that accept only `Wrap Int`.

Comment: Yes, I have tried this - with and without the restriction `instance (Num a) => MixedRing (Wrap a) where` - and it didn't help.

Comment: But this is because of your implementation of .*., see `dblhelix` comment.